# get option value with match in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have any value number such az 702(3) in option,i can get number between parenthesis from this code:

```
alert($('#at_exam_'+val+' option').filter(":selected").val().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]);
```

how to can get 702 in option value?

```
<select name="at_exam_1" id="at_exam_1">
  <option value="702(3)">test - (حاوی 3 سوال)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samuel has the right idea.

```
.val().match(/^(\d+)/);
```

or

```
.val().split('(')[0];
```

or

```
.val().replace(/\(\d+\)/,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
match(/^\d+/)
```

Code:

```
alert($('#at_exam_'+val+' option').filter(":selected").val().match(/^\d+/));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/qPSHF/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#at_exam_1').change(function(){
      console.log(parseInt($(this).val()));
});
```